# How to send multiple emails to multiple recipients?

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to send multiple emails to a list of email addresses from an Excel worksheet.

I have an Excel file with list of departments & manager.

I need to send each manager an email for each department with some information.

I need the 'Rows' value to remain for the next email (trying to do it with Do Until loop) - but after the first mail is generated, all the variables are initialized.

How can I keep the 'Rows' value for the next email?

```vb
Sub Sample()
    
    Dim olApp As Object    
    Dim olMailItm As Object    
    Dim SDest As String    
    Dim Class As Variant    
    Dim Originator As Variant    
    Dim Rows As Integer    
           
    'Create the Outlook application and the empty email.    
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")    
    Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)    
           
    With olMailItm    
        Rows = 2    
        Set Class = Cells(Rows, 3)    
        Originator = Cells(Rows, 4)    
            
        SDest = ""    
               
        Do Until Cells(Rows, 3) <> Class    
            SDest = Cells(Rows, 6).Value & ";" & Cells(Rows, 7).Value    
            Rows = Rows + 1          
        Loop    
        
        .Display    
        .To = SDest    
        .Subject = Cells(Rows, 3)    
        .Body = "Hello"    
    End With    
        
    Set olMailItm = Nothing    
    Set olApp = Nothing    
End Sub
```

Comment: You may wanna post sample of your Excel Sheet.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT to answer comments.

We create a email_dispatcher that creates an email for each destinatary.

Public outlookApp As Outlook.Application

```
Sub email_Dispatcher()
    Set outlookApp = New Outlook.Application
    Dim SDest As String
    Dim Class As Variant
    Dim Originator As Variant
    Dim Rows As Integer
    Dim tempRow As Integer
    Rows = 2
    tempRow = Rows
    Set Class = Cells(tempRows, 3)
    While Cells(tempRows, 3) <> Class
        SDest = Cells(tempRows, 6).Value & ";" & Cells(tempRows, 7).Value
        create_Email SDest, Class, "Hello"
    Wend
   Set Class = Cells(Rows, 3)
   Originator = Cells(Rows, 4)
End Sub

Sub create_Email(SDest As String, Subject As String, Body As String)
    Dim olMailItm As Object
    Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    With olMailItm
        .To = SDest
        .Subject = Cells(Rows, 3)
        .Body = "Hello"
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but it's still not working. since tempRows = Rows, they both return to value of 2...

Comment: Is this Sample() sub inside a loop? You can eliminate "tempRows = Rows" and the variable will mantain at the last value of the Do Untill Loop. You will just need to initialize it outside of the main loop

Comment: Sample() sub is all the code I have for now. How can I put it inside an additional loop? I also thought about it but i'm just stating to learn VBA.. I have no clue.

Comment: I edited my comment to try to answer your question. I hope I'm understanding that this is your problem

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried to use the code but I get an error window "ByRef argument type mismatch" :/

Comment: I haven't personally tested the code :c, put create_Email SDest, Class.value, "Hello"